# How to populate data into devexpress gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

im just learning how to build web application using devexpress in asp.net mvc. I faced a problem when trying to bind DevExpress.GridView.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult UploadedIndividualViewPartial()
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server = DESKTOP-FSET3FF; Database = ECIF_DATA; User Id = sa; Password = Copoe113"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UploadedPotentialDataIndividu", cn);
            cn.Open();
            ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }

        return PartialView("_UploadedPotentialDataIndividual"); // How can i pass data from sql query above into grid view
    }
```

and here is my PartialView:

```
@{
    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "GridApproveView";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "UploadedPotentialDataMerge", Action = "UploadedIndividualViewPartial"};
        settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
        settings.SettingsPager.PageSize = 32;
        settings.Height = 200;
        settings.Settings.VerticalScrollBarMode = ScrollBarMode.Auto;
        settings.ControlStyle.Paddings.Padding = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
        settings.ControlStyle.Border.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
        settings.ControlStyle.BorderBottom.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(1);
        settings.SettingsEditing.ShowModelErrorsForEditors = true;
        settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.EditFormAndDisplayRow;
        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
        settings.ClientSideEvents.SelectionChanged = "SelectionApproveChanged";
        settings.KeyFieldName = "ECIFCandidate";
        settings.SettingsDetail.AllowOnlyOneMasterRowExpanded = false;
        settings.SettingsDetail.ShowDetailRow = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowSelectCheckbox = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterBar = GridViewStatusBarMode.Visible;
        settings.SetDetailRowTemplateContent(c =>
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(
               "ECIF REF: <b>" +
                   DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "ECIFCandidate") + "</b>"
               );
            Html.RenderAction("GridDetailViewPartial", new { ECIF = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "ECIFCandidate") });
        });
 });
}@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

I still wonder how to bind data from sql query in controller into partialview. Can u show me a simple code how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass data from the action

```
return PartialView("_UploadedPotentialDataIndividual", ds[0]);
```

and add to the top of  partial view

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
```

Comment: Its give me hint to solve my problem. Thanks